# Why does PyCharm not catch type error between Optional[int] and Optional[str]?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

I'm a little confused as to why PyCharm doesn't distinguish between two different Optional types.

Consider the following code.

```py
def funcs(foo:Optional[str]=None):
    print(foo)

def funci(var:Optional[int]=None):
    funcs(var)

argi = 1
args = "something"
argn = None

funcs(argi)
funcs(args)
funcs(argn)
```

Notice the `funcs` call inside `funci` doesn't see a problem with passing in an Optional[int] to a function that is looking for an `Optional[str]`.

[image]

And yet, if we remove the `Optional[str]` the inspection barks.

[image]

**Is this expected behavior?** If yes, what can I do about it?

My gut says type checking should be smart enough to tell the difference between `Optional[str]` vs `Optional[int]`.  I've read through [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) and [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to no avail.

Comment: Optional can be None ... None intersects both signatures so its "OK" from a linter point of view ... at least thats my guess.... as soon as you remove the optional it can only be a str, str does not intersect with either `int or None`

Comment: The primary reasoning makes sense.  I am going to update my original question to ask "What can I do about it?"

Comment: most likely you can create custom lint rule ... in java as a plugin for idea ... but that seems like alot of work (or you can file a bug with jetbrains ... but you might be waiting a while)

Comment: What about style or coding options?  I *can* live with this particular "bug", but I keep thinking there is a work around I'm simply not seeing.

Comment: I saw your comment but didn't get here in time to address it. So I'll try to explain in the comments. The PyCharm linter is full of bugs when it comes to static type hint checks (syntax, PEP 8, style, all works fine, but not checking the PEP 484 type hints). So the **tl;dr** is, if you  write Python code with type hints you have to check it with mypy - let me stress that: you must use mypy.

Comment: The reasons are hard to explain, type hints are not only complex but have also been constantly changing. At some point the PyCharm devs gave up on fully supporting type hints (the IDE checks a few right, but not all). So why doesn't mypy ship with PyCharm to get 100%? Because mypy is 3rd party open source and PyCharm is proprietary. So they couldn't bundle free software with their commercial license. Anyway, bottom-line is you should use `Optional` but you have to check it for correctness using mypy and ignore the PyCharm Linter. (There's no way around this.)

Comment: When it comes to mypy vs pycharm, I'm slowly finding that neither are perfect; which of course is frustrating.  While mypy tends to be the standard it's annoying to have to go outside the IDE to have to utilize.  I'm slowly starting to come around to this way of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you test this in the current version of PyCharm (2021.1) with default inspection settings, the second warning after removal of the `Optional` type hint in the `funcs` parameter is no longer issued.

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes, the linter is (was) correct. A type has to be fully compatible otherwise there could be potential errors, the linter is right in warning you. In the stricter sense PyCharm should have issued a warning also in the first case because of the potential incompatibility between `str` and `int`.

Lets use the [Mypy static type checker](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) because its results are in general more accurate.

The following:

```py
def funcs(foo: Optional[str] = None):
    pass

def funci(var: Optional[int] = None):
    funcs(var)
```

would cause Mypy to issue an error:

```
your_module.py: error: Argument 1 to "funcs" has incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "Optional[str]"
```

> If yes, what can I do about it?

Python uses [gradual typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#summary-of-gradual-typing) meaning as the code goes along the types can be inspected and thus gradually hinted for correctness.

If you check the type explicitly:

```py
def funci(var: Optional[int] = None):
    if var is None:
        funcs(var)
```

The Mypy static type checker issues no error. An alternative would also be using [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) if you were certain the value would be restricted to `None` before the line calling `funcs(var)`.